# How to find Xpath for Search on Angular Website

Tags: python, html, selenium, screen-scraping

I would like to conduct an automated search on an angular website with python. Having successfully tested the identification of the search field via Xpath for a simple Google search, I have difficulties to locate the correct Xpath of the following html. *In blue the html line for which I would like to have the Xpath on this [website](http://bl.clex.ch/app/de/systematic/fulltext_search)*

[image]

as text:

```
<div class="input-group">
      <input autofocus="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="term" type="search" placeholder="Suchen">
    </div>
```

I tried the following (and a few more) using `WebDriverWait` as well as `find_element_by_xpath`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
    "//input[@class='form-control auto-complete ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-editable ng-empty ng-touched' and @type='search']")))

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Suchen"]').send_keys('AYT')

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[class='form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched']")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Xpath=//div[text()='Suchen']").click()
```

Why is none of these working? What works and why?

Comment: Picture of code does not help. Consider providing it in text format.

Comment: part or the entire html as text? added part of it

Comment: Yes, or link to Pastebin, So that user can easily test.

Answer (score 1):

fixed code:

```
search_input_locator = "//input[@placeholder='Suchen']"
search_button_locator = "//button[text()='Suchen']"

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,search_input_locator)))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_input_locator).send_keys('AYT')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,search_button_locator)))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_button_locator).click()
```

Your mistakes:

1. `@class='form-control auto-complete ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-editable ng-empty ng-touched'` - it's a bad practice to use strict comparison for class because it changes too often. Let's use someting like that `//*[contains(@class, 'one_class_name')]`
2. Wrong locator `//div[text()='Suchen']`, correct: `//button[text()='Suchen']`

Answer (score 1):

To start make sure you are using the Chrome browser. While you are viewing your source code, right click the element (in this case the `<input>` tag and then do Copy > Copy XPath.

[image: screen shot of how to select the XPath within Chrome browser]